# Character encoding on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, debian, filesystems, encoding

I have a problem with filenames on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The files get uploaded by a webserver that runs Linux, on that machine there is a mount to our windows machine. When we upload files certain characters are shown in a weird way, to give you an example.

`Kirchstraße.pdf` becomes `Kirchstra+â+©e.pdf`

I tried to solve this problem by using tool called `convmv` this tool takes an input encoding and you can tell it to use a specific output encoding.

But then I have to know the current encoding which I don't know. Does anyone know how to get the current encoding of a filename?

Does anyone of you had a similar problem and maybe knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your mount option to include a **iocharset=utf8**

> //host/share /mnt/share cifs
>   username=user,noperm,sec=ntlm,**iocharset=utf8** 0 0